# Maximal ideals give rise to bounded multiplicative linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, group-homomorphism, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am studying functional analysis. In the context of Banach algebras and their spaces of homomorphisms, my professor mentioned that "in commutative Banach algebras, maximal ideals give rise to bounded multiplicative linear functionals". I never took group theory (at any even introductory level), but I can read the Wiki definition of the maximal ideal. I am trying to develop some more intuition for this statement. Any examples for me to work through? Any more details about how it happens?

Comment: You quotient by the maximal ideal. By the Gelfand-Mazur theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) the result is $\mathbb{C}$, so the quotient map is the desired linear functional. It is going to be difficult for you to understand Banach algebras without having at least a little background in abstract algebra...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks! I can feel it already. Any particular topics/maybe textbook that I can go through in abstract algebra? Or concepts?